# Rails 3. How to find an associated model through another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have these models: Expenses, ScheduledCourses and ScheduledSessions.

```
scheduled_courses has_many scheduled_sessions
scheduled_sessions belongs_to scheduled_courses

expenses has_many scheduled_sessions
scheduled_sessions belongs_to expenses
```

I need to find all the expenses associated with a particular scheduled_course. But the expenses have a scheduled_session_id not a scheduled_course_id.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

scheduled_course:

```
has_many :expenses, :through => :scheduled_sessions
```